# How much it takes the updateTable operation? I need to update 800.000 items and I want to disable the stream before each update and enable it after

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, amazon-dynamodb-streams

This is an code example:

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        var paramsEnable = {
          TableName: 'yourTableName', 
          StreamSpecification: {
            StreamEnabled: false
          }
        };
        
        dynamodb.updateTable(paramsDisable, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
        //  
        //My code here
        //
        var paramsEnable = {
          TableName: 'yourTableName', 
          StreamSpecification: {
            StreamEnabled: true    
          }
        };
        
        dynamodb.updateTable(paramsEnable , function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
```

I want to know how can I do it in a beter way? to add 2 updates after each updateItem operation is not the best..And I need to disable the stream because it will invoke another 4 functions.Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this disable/enable dance. I don't know what you mean by it will invoke another 4 functions. If you want lambdas to ignore the updates, add an event filter on some attribute present on the inserted items you don't want handled.

Comment: What is "a better way"? You could use a step function to do that before and after your Lambda, but the API is the API. What are you looking to optimize for?

Comment: An Item has around 47 kb..the function is running around 2 hours for 80.00-100.000 Items

Comment: When an update is made on an item we have another functions to recalculate the progress,score etc.

Comment: I want just a quick answer, how much it takes to updateTable operation to disable/enable Stream?